# How to know if Lookup column is deferred or not using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I'm trying to use the REST APi to get data from a sharepoint list.
I first get the information about the columns: `_api/Web/List<guid'some-id')/Fields`.
Then with this information I query the data `_api/Web/Lists(guide'some-id')/Items?$top=5000`.
If any of the columns are of type `Lookup` or `LookupMulti` then I append the `&$select=<column_name>/Title` and `&$expand=<column_name>` to the url.

The issue is that only deferred `Lookup` columns can actually be returned by the REST API. If they are not then I get an error.

How can I figure out which `Lookup` columns are deferred or not? That way I won't try to expand those and my request won't fail.

Answer (score 0):

Once a query is submitted, then review the returned record and each lookup field that has a '__deferred' element is available for expansion through the `&$expand=Folder` term as an example.

If there are no associated records within the deferred field it will still show the '__deferred' element, which indicates that there is no child record present for this items field.